# How to mock JDBC Resultset in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, jdbc, mockito

I've followed all the required processes in the doc.However, the `rs.next()` never returns `true` even I mock it. Not sure where went wrong.

```
class XXXUnitTest extends AnyFunSuite {
  test("testExecuteSandboxInsertQuery") {
    val connection: Connection = Mockito.mock(classOf[Connection], RETURNS_MOCKS)
    val statement: PreparedStatement = Mockito.mock(classOf[PreparedStatement], RETURNS_MOCKS)
    val mockRS: ResultSet = Mockito.mock(classOf[ResultSet])
    when(connection.prepareStatement(insertToSandboxInfoTableQuery)).thenReturn(statement)
    when(mockRS.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false)
    when(statement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(mockRS)
    when(mockRS.getString("ims_org_id")).thenReturn("123")
    val actual = DBUtils.getImsOrgList(connection, getDistinctImsOrg)
    val expect = List("123")
    assert(actual == expect)
  }
 }
```

This is the version I am using:

- Scala Version: 2.11
- Mockito-scala.version: 1.16.0
- scalatest.version: 3.2.2

Comment: Is the query in `insertToSandboxInfoTableQuery` the same as what your `getImsOrgList` method uses? If not, `connection.prepareStatement(...)` won't return `statement`, it will return a different mock statement.  Have you tried removing `RETURNS_MOCKS`?  That will cause Mockito to return null values instead of mocks for methods that haven't been set up.  Doing this will likely give you a NullPointerException (or the Scala equivalent), but that should hopefully narrow down where the problem is.  Another possibility is to replace `insertIntoSandboxInfoTableQuery` with `anyString()`.

Comment: However, if I'm honest, there isn't a lot to be gained by unit-testing JDBC code in this way.  As you've seen, it's fairly complicated to do the setup.  Most methods that call out to JDBC have the same structure, so your tests would be repetitive.  Also, the unit tests don't test that the SQL strings are valid, that column names exist, that there are the right numbers of bind parameters, etc.  You would be better off testing this code with integration tests that access a real database.